# Make child element 100% height of parent max-height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a modal layout and struggling to pass height context from a parent element to its child element. Take a look at [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/tomblanchard/pen/WGWENx), `.child-child` needs to be the same height as `.child`.

One solution to this is changing `max-height: 50%;` to `height: 50%;`; this isn't usable because sometimes the modal won't contain that much content and should only be as high as the content it contains, then when there's a lot of content it shouldn't be able to exceed it's `max-height`.

Another solution is to go for flexbox and setting `.child` as a flex container which will set `.child-child` full height which flex containers do by default; you can see that in action in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/tomblanchard/pen/yaWZvz). This actually works great in most browsers and does exactly what I need, but completely fails in IE10/11+; note that I'm using autoprefixer in the CodePen settings so I doubt this'll be a flexbox syntax issue. Maybe I need to add some other flex properties for IE such as `flex-grow` / `flex-shrink` etc. I've tried a bunch of different combinations with not much luck, I also can't seem to find this specific bug with Google either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Must child be 50% of the screen? or can it be bigger?

Comment: @paolobasso Always 50%.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only possibility solution is making .child scrollale with overflow-y:scroll;.

My Demo.

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}

.child {
 background: blue;
 max-height: 50%;
 max-width: 600px;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
padding: 20px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}

.child-child {
 background: green;
  height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}
 <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
     <div class="child-child">
      <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
       <p>Blah.</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Edit If you want to put the button you can BUT you must set position:relative to .child and  position:fixed to the button;

Working DEMO.

Edit If you want to position the buttom on right you must use right:calc((100% - 600px)/2);.

Working DEMO.

P.S. see calc() browser support there.

Comment: Yeah I get this, but the flexbox solution covers this and handles it exactly how I need it, just the IE bug is holding that back. 

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only possibility solution is making `.child` scrollale with `overflow-y:scroll;`.

My [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/q5ydf6z8/).

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  max-height: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.child-child {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-child">
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. If you want to keep the padding you have to apply `overflow-y:scroll;` to a child container.

**Edit**
If you want to put the button you can BUT you must set `position:relative` to `.child` and `position:fixed` to the button;

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/q5ydf6z8/1/).

**Edit**
If you want to position the buttom on right you must use `right:calc((100% - 600px)/2);`.

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/q5ydf6z8/2/).

P.S. see `calc()` browser support [there](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Comment: This is actually really close, the only problem is that in reality there's gonna be a close button top right absolutely positioned [like this](http://codepen.io/tomblanchard/pen/NRVNvy); this button needs to persist at this position even when the content has been scrolled. Thanks for the input, super appreciated!

Comment: Oooh so close! I can't seem to find a way to position the button to the top right of the modal inner container though, [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fsmkpr3a/3/); any ideas?

Comment: What about putting the button outside child? and inside parent

Comment: Can't do that because I need the close button to be position top right of the blue BG content box.

Comment: That's not gonna work in a responsive environment :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126853/discussion-between-paolobasso-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.plus-btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.parent').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.plus-btn {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.plus-btn span {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 45% 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  pointer-events: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.plus-btn span:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.plus-btn span:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.parent.active .plus-btn span:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.parent.active .plus-btn span:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.child {
  background: blue;
  max-height: 50vh;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
}

.child-child {
  background: green;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .3s;
  transition: max-height .3s;
}
.parent.active .child-child {
  max-height: calc(50vh - 40px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="top-right">
      <div class="plus-btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-child">
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p><p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
      <p>Blah.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, `.child` now has an explicit height (`height: 100%;`), so when the modal doesn't contain a lot of content [like this](http://codepen.io/tomblanchard/pen/EgzKjr) the modal is taller than it needs to be, the modal should only be as tall as the content is contains and no taller than 50% of the screen. Thanks for the help though Trevor!

Comment: @Tom I've made some changes to my post. Will this work?

Comment: Almost, I experimented with viewport units also; but I can't go that route due to all the iOS bugs :( Thanks again for the input dude.

Comment: Interesting. I pulled it up on my phone with no issues. Also, http://caniuse.com/#search=vh is showing no issues since iOS 7.1

Comment: I updated the code to have a open and close button. Again, I don't think you should be worried about using `vh` in your code the way it's used here. It should be pretty well supported.